# Determine local maximum from given points

Tags: python, performance

How could I make this code more effective?  I'm just experimenting and learning the different ways of how Python runs.

```
list=[]
original=mkPoint3D(x,y)
z1=mkPoint3D(x-d,y)
z2=mkPoint3D(x+d,y)
z3=mkPoint3D(x,y-d)
z4=mkPoint3D(x,y+d)
list.append(original)
list.append(z1)
list.append(z2)
list.append(z3)
list.append(z4)

if(maxPoint(list).z==original.z):
    print("The local maximum is at " + "( " + str(original.x) + " , "  + str(original.y) + " )" + " = " + str(original.z))
elif maxPoint(list).z==z1.z:
    hillClimb(z1.x,z1.y,d)
elif maxPoint(list).z==z2.z:
    hillClimb(z2.x,z2.y,d)
elif maxPoint(list).z==z3.z:
    hillClimb(z3.x,z3.y,d)
elif maxPoint(list).z==z4.z:
    hillClimb(z4.x,z4.y,d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use "list" as a variable name, since it is a python function.
Don't initialize it a list and append to it, if you can
just create it and populate it with one line.
Don't call a function more than once, if you don't need to.
Use a loop with a break statement, instead of all the elif statements

```
original=mkPoint3D(x,y)
z1=mkPoint3D(x-d,y)
z2=mkPoint3D(x+d,y)
z3=mkPoint3D(x,y-d)
z4=mkPoint3D(x,y+d)

point_list = [original, z1, z2, z3, z4]

maxz = maxPoint(point_list).z

if maxz == original.z:
    print (" The local ...")

else:
    for next_point in point_list[1:]:
        if maxz == next_point.z:
            matching_point = next_point
            break

    hillClimb(matching_point.x, matching_point.y, d)
```